# iPhone-Load The UIViewController only after HTTP Request in the appdelegate completes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have am creating an app in which i read a JSON feed and store the content json in a file. And each time when the user opens the app I send a http request and update the content in the file.

Now, when I call the HTTP request in the Appdelegeate's "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function, the Http request runs in another thread and my app loads with the previous data from the file all the time.

1. Is there a way to read the file only after the HTTP request is done

Note: i have all the Http connections in an Supporting file called HTTP.h and HTTP.m

Thanks!

Comment: Where you are loading file content?I think you should load file content once when data/response is received.

Comment: Yes. But that response is in the HTTP.m file and from there how do I load the data in the viewController page?

Comment: You can use notification.Once data is received post the notification which will call the selector in your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest method. But I think what you are doing is not the right way to go about things. Making the user wait before he can use the UI seems like a very bad user experience to me.